# Retrieve lineal regression from scatterplot in GEE

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, scatterplot

I'm trying to get a lineal regression from scatterplot of two bands in GEE, but i don't how to do It. I was trying to apply over the example of scatterplot available in GEE docs.

```
// Define an arbitrary region of interest.
var sanFrancisco = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-122.45, 37.74, -122.4, 37.8]);

// Load a Landsat 8 image.
var image = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA/LC08_044034_20140318');

// Get a dictionary with band names as keys, pixel lists as values.
var result = image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.toList(), sanFrancisco, 120);

// Convert the band data to plot on the y-axis to arrays.
var y1 = ee.Array(result.get('B5'));
var y2 = ee.Array(result.get('B6'));
// Concatenate the y-axis data by stacking the arrays on the 1-axis.
var yValues = ee.Array.cat([y1, y2], 1);

// The band data to plot on the x-axis is a List.
var xValues = result.get('B4');

// Make a band correlation chart.
var chart = ui.Chart.array.values(yValues, 0, xValues)
    .setSeriesNames(['B5', 'B6'])
    .setOptions({
      title: 'LC8 TOA B4 vs. {B5,B6}',
      hAxis: {'title': 'B4'},
      vAxis: {'title': '{B5,B6}'},
      pointSize: 3,
});

// Print the chart.
print(chart);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just want to chart trendlines in your graph:

```
// Make a band correlation chart.
var chart = ui.Chart.array.values(yValues, 0, xValues)
    .setSeriesNames(['B5', 'B6'])
    .setOptions({
      title: 'LC8 TOA B4 vs. {B5,B6}',
      hAxis: {'title': 'B4'},
      vAxis: {'title': '{B5,B6}'},
      pointSize: 3,
      trendlines: { 0: {showR2: true, visibleInLegend: true} , 
                    1: {showR2: true, visibleInLegend: true}}
});
```

And you can get the values for the slope and offset in the chart using:

```
print('Linear fit output B4 vs B5',
          ee.Array.cat([xValues, y1], 1).reduce(ee.Reducer.linearFit(),[0],1));
print('Linear fit output B4 vs B6',
          ee.Array.cat([xValues, y2], 1).reduce(ee.Reducer.linearFit(),[0],1));
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/1802d1451538ceff069dcc7f20a086a7)

Comment: Hi, I know this question is a bit old but it was the only one I could find which indicates how to retrieve the R2 value from a linear fit, except when applying the code I could only get the slope and offset, am I misunderstanding something? Thanks!

Comment: Yes you are right. It gives the offset and slope, not the R2 value. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already compiled your values in **yValues** object, you can use the linear fit reducer to obtain the constants.

```
print(yValues.reduce(ee.Reducer.linearFit(),[0],1))
```

The above line should get you the value of constants for the linear fit. The reducer takes 3 parameters among which first is the reducer, second is the axis (or axes) of features and third is the axis of a single feature that contains the values for x and y of the regression.
Keep in mind though, since it takes order of the columns for identifying input and output, the constants you get would be different if you did

```
var yValues = ee.Array.cat([y2, y1], 1);
```